# How do you remove duplicates in a 2d list with the same values but different order

Tags: python, duplicates

I have a list which contains lists. I am trying to remove any duplicates of lists which may share the same items within the list but in a different order.

for example if I have this

```
nestedlist=[[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[1,5,8,7]]
```

I would like a function that returns something like:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,5,8,7]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list after acessing sub list and compare accordingly.

```
new=[]
nestedlist=[[1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1],[1,5,8,7]]
for i in nestedlist:
    if sorted(i) not in new:
        new.append(i)

print(new)
```

Gives #

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: This approach is very inefficient if your lists are long. Comparing lists is O(n). Membership test in lists is O(n). Sorting is O(n log n). This approach is like O(n^3)?

Comment: Agree..@PranavHosangadi..Just posted solution I've in mind...I even tried your solution..It's working fine...Maybe OP not worrying about long lists?

Answer (score 1):

Make a set of sets out of the list of lists. Then convert it back to a list of lists:

```
sos = {frozenset(l) for l in nestedlist}
unique_nested = [list(s) for s in sos]
```

We need to use `frozenset` instead of `set` because sets are mutable therefore not hashable